# Check if a string is a hostname or an ip-address in Java

Tags: java, string, ip-address, hostname

I want to check if a string is a hostname or an ip-address in Java. Is there an API to do it or must I write a parser myself?

The problem is complex because there are IPv4 addresses, short and long IPv6 addresses, short hostnames and FQDN host names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could theoretically write rules to handle these cases yourself, using [the](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc791.txt) [usual](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2460.txt) [cadre](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4703.txt) of [RFCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments), I'd instead look at [the entirety of this class in Google Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html), especially the corner cases, such as how it resolves the embedding of 4-in-6 addresses.

As for determining if you have a FQDN, see if coercion to IP address fails, then try to resolve it against DNS. Anything else should, given your input cases, be a hostname or local resolution that isn't fully qualified.

Comment: It doesn't look like Guava's class indicates whether a String contains a hostname (non-IP address).

Answer (score 6):

There doesn't appear to be an API, but writing such function doesn't seem to be very difficult. You can check the following conditions in your code:

1. If sourceStr contains ":" but no "." -> IPv6
2. If sourceStr.matches("^.[0-9]{1,3}/..[0-9]{1,3}/..[0-9]{1,3}/..[0-9]{1,3}") == true) -> IPv4
3. If sourceStr contains "." -> FQDN host name
4. Otherwise it must be a short hostname

Answer (score 3):

To expand @MrGomez 's answer, Use [InetAddresses](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html) to validate IP Addresses and [InternetDomainName](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html#isValid(java.lang.String)) to validate hostnames (FQDN).

Example:

```
public static boolean validate(final String hostname) {
        return InetAddresses.isUriInetAddress(hostname) || InternetDomainName.isValid(hostname);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not possible in JDK API but you can use `InetAddresses.forString` in [google guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) which throws exception when argument is not a IP string literal.

Answer (score 2):

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will do it.  The javadoc is available at the link.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```
static void check(HostName host) {
    try {
        host.validate();
        if(host.isAddress()) {
            System.out.println("address: " + host.asAddress());
        } else {
            System.out.println("host name: " + host);
        }
    } catch(HostNameException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HostName host = new HostName("1.2.3.4");
    check(host);
    host = new HostName("1.2.a.4");
    check(host);
    host = new HostName("::1");
    check(host);
    host = new HostName("[::1]");
    check(host);
    host = new HostName("1.2.?.4");
    check(host);  
}
```

Output:

```
address: 1.2.3.4
host name: 1.2.a.4
address: ::1
address: ::1
1.2.?.4 Host error: invalid character at index 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
import sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil
IPAddressUtil.isIPv4LiteralAddress(addr)
IPAddressUtil.isIPv6LiteralAddress(addr)
```

Comment: You should edit this to add an explanation for what these commands do, just posting code as a solution isn't helpful.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.